# One line of angular code works in jsfiddle but not in plunkr

Tags: angularjs

I tried to copy some code over from `jsfiddle` to `plunkr`. I've got it almost working at `plunkr`, except for the last ng-repeat (the one with timeslot):

```
<div ng-controller="taskViewCtrl">
    <table style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody ng-model="subtasks">
            <tr ng-repeat="subtask in subtasks" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
                <td>{{$index}} Worker {{subtask.workerId}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="timeslot in subtask.subtaskArray">{{timeslot}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/frodefi/dJrG7/17/

**plunkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0IdwZCowqOGp4lco7V90?p=preview

They use two different Angular versions (`1.02` vs `1.2.7`), but I am sure the problem is not there. Most probably I have made a mistake somewhere, but where?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in different angular versions? Have you noticed the big red _"Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed ..."_ error in the console.

Comment: In neither plunkr nor jsfiddle I get a such error in the console (I am using Chrome)... Regarding versions, I will try to change versions and see what happens then...

Comment: Did also change the version in plunker to be the same as in jsfiddle, that did not help either...

Comment: Oh, sorry Stewie, I was testing on a different version. Your are of course correct regarding the error. And also the version! Put it up as an answer and I could accept it? But then, how to get this to work as intended for the new version of Angular?

Comment: To get it to work in the new version of Angular, I had to make follow this example:  ng-repeat-start="subtask in subtasks track by $index", since the ng-repeat needs all array-elements are unique. So it is for example not allowed with [0,0,0,1,1,1,1] (my case). This is solved by "track by" (and $index).